# need help on a mysql query to make it work

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table that has unique user id's and the servers they connect to.

How do I look up users who have only been connected to server A and server B on a certain day but never connected to other servers (server C or D... etc)

This query isn't working for me:

```
select distinct user_id from table where server="A" and server="B"
```

Comment: use **`OR`** in place of **`AND`**.  Or, **`where server IN ('A','B')`**.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to count the number of times the user connected to each server each day, then filter for counts > 0 for servers A and B, plus a count of zero for other servers.

This first query will result in one row per user per day, with counts for servers A, B, and "not A or B":

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  connect_date
  COUNT(CASE WHEN server = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS ServerA,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN server = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS ServerB,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN server NOT IN ('A', 'B') THEN 1 END) AS ServerOther
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id, connect_date
```

Push the first query into a subquery, then filter on the server A/B/other values:

```
SELECT user_id, connect_date
FROM (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    connect_date
    COUNT(CASE WHEN server = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS ServerA,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN server = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS ServerB,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN server NOT IN ('A', 'B') THEN 1 END) AS ServerOther
  FROM table
  GROUP BY user_id, connect_date
) perUser
WHERE
  ServerA > 0 AND ServerB > 0 AND ServerOther = 0
```

I've included a date because your question mentions "within a certain day". If this doesn't work for you please post your table structure and specify if you mean "a specific day" or "on any day".

Comment: Fair call @Strawberry - you're 100% right. That was nothing more than a careless opening phrase. There's no way I'd pound the table and shout this is the best way, especially since there's precious little in the question to go on. I've changed it to a more defensible (and accurate) "One way to do this...".

Answer (score 0):

To check for values of `user_id` where at least one row with `server` equal to 'A' or 'B', but row exists where `server` is equal to 'C' or 'D', you could do something like this:

```
  SELECT t.user_id 
    FROM mytable t
   GROUP BY t.user_id 
  HAVING MAX(t.server IN ('A','B')) 
     AND NOT ( MAX(t.server IN ('C','D')) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

SELECT  user_id  FROM  table

WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE server='A')

AND server='B'

This will (hopefully) fetch the user-id's that are connected with server 'A' & server 'B' both.

Hope this helps..!

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id 
  from table 
where server in('A','B')
 group
  by user_id
having count(distinct server) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select userid,server,count(*) as AB from server where server='A' OR server='B' group by userid;
```

> You can try this.. in AB if value>1 than user login both server A and B.Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MySQL, you can write this query using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT server ORDER BY server) AS servers
FROM table 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING servers = "A,B";
```

which finds and concatenates all servers related to each user_id, and then filters the result such that only rows containing just the desired servers are returned.